# Identify a mid to late 80s comic, possibly 2000AD

Tags: story-identification, comics

There's very little to go on.

It had a 2000AD sort of art style and vibe (it may even have been a 2000AD storyline). It had a group of mercenary/anti-hero types. They were mixed gender and race (but all humanoids) and I think they had a ship call "The Pig". It may have been a kind of dropship. They might have been some sort of kill-team. One of the females may have been psychic.

That's it...

Comment: What's a drop ship?

Comment: Like a shuttle, takes combat units to the surface from a bigger ship in orbit.

Answer (score 1):

The 2000AD mixed gender/race humanoid mercenaries suggests that it might have been Strontium Dogs.

They were all mutants - Durham Red was a woman with a mutation which mimicked vampirism and may have included psychic powers/mind control.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strontium_Dog